# Closed contour within a closed contour integral

Tags: complex-numbers, contour-integration

Let $C$ and $D$ be two closed contours, $D$ lying completely within $C$, and let $a$ be a point between $C$ and $D$. Show that:

$$
f(a) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{C}\frac{f(z)}{z-a}dz - \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_D \frac{f(z)}{z-a}dz.
$$

I am confused because I thought this would be trivial, using Cauchy's Integral Theorem.

Comment: What must the integral over $D$ be by Cauchy's theorem?

Comment: Where is $f$ holomorphic?

Comment: It is holomorphic at a, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  In order to use Cauchy's Theorem, you need a single closed curve.  If you consider a path $E$ from a point in $C$ to a point in $D$, then you can "join" $C$ and $D$ into a single curve.  (You might want to draw a picture.)

Of course, you'd like to be able to cancel any integration over $E$ - why can you do this?

Comment: This hint assumes that $f$ is holomorphic between $C$ and $D$.